# Draw text on Canvas with custom Height - Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing2d

I'm drawing text on canvas with this code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(50);

        paint.getTextBounds(first, 0, first.length(), bounds);
        canvas.drawText(first, (canvas.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2, 50, paint);
    }
```

Here is result:

[image: First]

But I want the text to have bigger height, I want something like this:

[image: Second]

I don't want to change the font size, only the height of this text. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this:

```
// Closing hardware acceleration
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);

paint.getTextBounds(first, 0, first.length(), bounds);
float posX = (canvas.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2; // center
float posY = ((canvas.getHeight() - bounds.height()) / 2); // center

canvas.scale(1, 10, posX, posY);
canvas.drawText(first, posX, posY, paint);
```

Comment: Is that possible to have some explanation ?

Comment: canvas.scale(1, 10, posX, posY); I'm only scaling the height by 10